# How to pass non-english chars in an api post command

Tags: powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

I am writing a powershell script and trying to run a post command with an Azure DevOps api, but one of my values contains non-english characters and the Invoke-RestMethod always fails with:
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"You must pass a valid patch document in the body of the request.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssPropertyValidationException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common","typeKey":"VssPropertyValidationException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
If I remove the non-english chars, it works as expected.

What do I need to do, to get the non-english chars to be accepted in the json body.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Just needed to add ";charset=UTF-8" to my content type.